# Broadcast receiver isn't starting the intended service on device restart

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I have set up a broadcast receiver in my app and I expect it to start a service when my device restarts...This service should push a notification...But the service isn't getting triggered..Please tell me where I am going wrong..This is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.conquer_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/conquer_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/conquer_icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/conquerBackgroundColor" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".AlarmHandlerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".DemoService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

RebootBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.conquer_app;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class RebootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, DemoService.class);
            context.startService(newIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

DemoService.java

```
package com.conquer_app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class DemoService extends Service {


    public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(String title, String content) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "task_reminders")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotification("service is started", "").build();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotification("Demo Service works", "can add my DB now...").build();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `BroadcastReceiver` getting called on device boot? Are your sure?

Comment: Also, what version of Android is your test device running?

Comment: Android 10...and how can I know if the broadcast receiver is getting called? The notification I intend it to push doesn't get pushed so maybe it isn't!

Comment: add debug logging in `onReceive()` that writes to logcat or something similar.

Comment: Also, what is in `onCreate()` of `MainApplication`? Because that will get called **before** your `BroadcastReceiver` is instantiated. Maybe that has some issues during the boot process. You could also add debug logging there.